# NullReferenceException, ListView Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I'm getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error with my code below and im not sure why. All my variables are being set, i even had some code before it checking if any of them are null and it never stopped there it just crashed on the line specified.

Code:

```
    private async void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        passArguments result = (passArguments)e.Argument;
        e.Result = result;

        while (running >= 5)
        {
            string[] row = { "Waiting", result.passedFileName };
            var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
            listViewItem.ImageIndex = 1;
            listView1.Items[result.passedNum] = (listViewItem); //<--- error here

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
        running++;
//other code
    }

    private async void backgroundWorker3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //other code
        running--;
    }
```

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Stack Trace

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewNativeItemCollection.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewNativeItemCollection.set_Item(Int32 displayIndex, ListViewItem value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.set_Item(Int32 index, ListViewItem value)
       at ***.Form1.<backgroundWorker3_DoWork>d__c.MoveNext() in ***\Form1.cs:line 378
  InnerException:
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing here to cause this issue?

Comment: Well, where does the debugger show the error?

Comment: @OldProgrammer On the line I said in the code above.
"istView1.Items[result.passedNum] = (listViewItem);"

Comment: 1 of 2 things is null.  `listView1`, or `result`  you can use the [Debugger](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging) to see which of them is null.  Visual Studio should set up a breakpoint for you when you hit an uncaught exception.

Comment: @SamIam, `Items[result.passedNum]` could also be null.

Comment: @SamIam It not hitting any of them
`if (listView1 == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("lv1");
                }
                if (result == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("resualt");
                }`

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino You are right it is null but why? `if (listView1.Items[result.passedNum] == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("listView1.Items");
                }`

Comment: Code is a fair abomination, you'll have to make up your mind if you are going to use a BackgroundWorker or a Task or async/await, don't do *everything*.   What might happen is hard to guess without any context but the stack trace shows that the code does not run on the UI thread.  It is illegal to access a control from a worker thread.

Comment: @RuneFS well observed. I wonder if OP can tell us what is the **type** of `listView1`.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino if `Items[result.passedNum]` were null it would still run.

Comment: @SamIam, RuneFS just made me realize that. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino what do you mean? Its a System.Windows.Forms.ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `listViewItem` if you can't find it on the `Items` collection.

```
if (!listView1.Items.Contains(result.passedNum))
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

**Warning**: this will work but you should consider a way to avoid too much searches on the list (`Contains()`) on larger iterations.

Comment: I tried 
`if (listView1.Items.Count > result.passedNum)
                {
                    listView1.Items[result.passedNum] = (listViewItem);
                }`
but im still getting a "'System.NullReferenceException' " inside of the if statment

Comment: also adding a new one `listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);` just spams the listview with new items, I shouldent need to use this as it should already exsist

Comment: What is the type of `listView1`?

Comment: Its a System.Windows.Forms.ListView

Comment: Do you know a better way to do this? what about a try statement, and if it fails it will then add the item?

Comment: Just do it outside of the loop. And I don't think a try/catch would be recommended. Avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: What if i just check if its null inside?
`if (listView1.Items[number] == null)
                    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);`